# Spring Kafka 1.1.3-SNAPSHOT's compatibility with Kafka 0.10.1.1

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am new to Kafka and I'd like to use the latest version which has streaming support (0.10.1.1).  I'd also like to use Spring Kafka.

I don't understand the version compatibility Spring Kafka says in its documentation:

This link says Apache Kafka 0.10.x.x client

http://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/1.1.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/whats-new-part.html

This link says: Apache Kafka 0.9.0.1

http://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/1.1.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/_introduction.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means that the highest supported version is indeed something the latest for 0.10.x.x.

But it is still compatible with Apache Kafka 0.9.0.1.

The best what you can have is transitive dependency from Spring Kafka:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
  <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
  <version>0.10.1.1</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

BTW: https://spring.io/blog/2017/02/06/spring-for-apache-kafka-1-1-3-available-now